# Seeking GeoNetwork documentation?

Tags: references, geonetwork

I am quite surprised with the lack of solid documentation regarding GeoNetwork 3.4.

Is there an ebook or paperback book I could buy, or are there any online resources I can refer to?

I am working with GeoServer and GeoNetwork and there are several aspects I would like to have reading material to rely on.

Comment: GeoNetwork 3.4 has not been out that long, and there have been quite a few changes over previous versions.  So start with https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.4.x/en/index.html  or https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/3.4.x/fr/index.html (a lot of the active developers are French) and ask question here if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been about 10 years since I did some prototyping using GeoNetwork, and my recollection is that it had adequate, if not copious, documentation.

If you are unable to locate any suitable references, then I recommend starting by reviewing our [self-assembling FAQ about GeoNetwork](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geonetwork?sort=frequent), and if you do not find what you need then start asking some focused questions on this site that describe what you want to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck.